# asp.net mvc javascript disable show and hide div

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ok the thing is that i have a div which show and hide based on the apply button.

1) if you press the apply button and the div is hidden it shows,

2) if the div is shown then it is hidden.

I am using javascript function . how can i make it shown if the javascript is disabled ?(by default it is hidden)

Answer (score 3):

use this code whtever u want to do when ur js is not enabled write in

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write("<p>JavaScript is enabled.</p>");
   </script>

     <noscript>
        JavaScript is not enabled or not supported.
     </noscript>
```